# Trying to write a specific result to a new outfile

Tags: perl, output, file-io

I am extremely new to the Perl process. I am very much enjoying the learning curve and Perl but I am frustrated beyond belief and have spent many, many hours on one task achieving little to no results.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
print "Average value of retroviruses for the length of each genome and each of the                     genes:\n"; #create a title for the script
my $infile = "Lab1_table.txt"; # This is the file path.
open INFILE, $infile or die "Can't open $infile: $!"; # Provides an error message if      the file can'tbe found.

# set my initial values.
my $tally = 0;
my @header = ();
my @averages = ();



 # create my first loop to run through the file by line.
while (my $line = <INFILE>){
chomp $line;
print "$line\n";

# add one to the loop and essentially remove the header line of value.
# the first line is what was preventing me from caclulating averages as Perl can't    calculate words.

my @row = split /\t/, $line; # split the file by tab characters.
$tally++; #adds one to the tally.
    if ( $tally == 1 ) { #if the tally = 1 the row is determined as a the header.
    @header = @row;
}

# if the tally is anything else besides 1 then it will read those rows.
else {
    for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @row; $i++ )  {
        $averages[$i] += $row[$i];
}

foreach my $element (@row){
}

foreach my $i (0..4){
    $averages[$i] = $averages[$i] + $row[1..4];

}
 }
 }

 print "Average values of genome, gag, pol and env:\n";

 for( my $i = 1; $i < scalar @averages; $i++ ) { # this line is used to determine the      averages of the columns and print the values
print $averages[$i]/($tally-1), "\n";
 }
```

SO, I got the results to come up with what I wanted (not in the exact format I wanted but as close as I can seem to get at the moment) and they do average the columns.

The issue now is writing to a an outfile. I am trying to get my table and results from the previous code to appear in my outfile. I get a good file name but no results.

```
  foreach my $i (1){
  my $outfile= "Average_values".".txt";
  open OUTFILE, ">$outfile" or die "$outfile: $!";
  print "Average values of genome, gag, pol and env:\n";
  }
  close OUTFILE;    



  close INFILE;
```

I feel like there is an easy way to do this and a hard way and I have taken the very hard way. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not tell Perl where to print:

```
print OUTFILE "Average values of genome, gag, pol and env:\n";
```

BTW, together with `use strict`, also `use warnings`. And for working with files, use lexical filehandles and the three argument form of `open`:

```
open my $FH, '>', $filename or die $!;
print $FH 'Something';
close $FH or die $!;
```

Comment: @choroba `print{$FH} 'word'` is better, do you think?

Comment: @loldop: I usually use it, too, with a space after `print`. Matter of taste.